# SQL Incorrect Percentage Calculations

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm currently writing up a small report and I have to create figures for target percentages however the query I have written seems to display incorrect calculations for percentages and I'm not entirely sure why. The query has removed all sensitive information;

```
SELECT  YearMonth
, Code
, COUNT(*) AS Total
, (COUNT(*) / 100 * 2) AS 'Q1 Target'
, (COUNT(*) / 100 * 3) AS 'Q2 Target'
, (COUNT(*) / 100 * 4) AS 'Q3 Target'
, (COUNT(*) / 100 * 5) AS 'Q4 Target'
FROM xxx
LEFT JOIN Calendar AS C ON Date = xxx
WHERE code IN (xxx)
and xxx BETWEEN '20220301' AND '20220331'
GROUP BY YearMonth, code
```

The results that are returned are;

[image]

As you can see, the first row has a total of 611 and 2% of that is 12 which is correct. However, if you look at the 3rd row, you can see that the total is 659 and 2% of that should be 13 but it is showing as 12. The same applies on the next column where 3% of 659 should be 19 but is showing as 18. Only whole integers are required so no need to cast.

Any reasons as to why this is happening?

Answer (score 5):

> Only whole integers are required so no need to cast.

Are you sure?

659 / 100 in integer division results in 6 and throws the remainder away. 6*2=12.

Change your `100`s to `100.0`s to force <del>float</del> decimal division. You might need some rounding/text functions to return to the pleasing two digits afterwards.

Comment: Ahh I see, I appreciate the fast response. I completely forgot that integer divisions removes points. Works a charm now!

Comment: Slight nitpick, but `100.0` isn't a float, it's a `decimal`. If you wanted a `float`, you could use `1e2` (though I recommend sticking to a `decimal`).

Comment: I was a bit skeptical of which word to choose, but then I thought, "Larnu will cover my tracks up if something goes wrong" :)

Comment: Alternative is to switch the `*` and `/` so that 659 * 2 = 1318 / 100 = 13